# Java generics

Tags: java, generics

Why is the following seen as better than the old way of casting?

`MyObj obj = someService.find(MyObj.class, "someId");`

vs.

`MyObj obj = (MyObj) someService.find("someId");`

Comment: Who says that this is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another advantage to using an explicit type parameter would be to allow the service method to be implemented using a `Proxy` (in this case `MyObj` would need to be `MyInterface`). Without explicit type parameters, this would not be possible.

You might use a `Proxy` under the covers for many reasons (testing for one)

Answer (score 9):

There's no guarantee that the non-generics version will return an object of type 'MyObj', so you might get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 6):

In case 1, most well-implemented services would be able to return null if there no object with id `someId` of type `MyObj` could be found.  Moreover, the first case makes it possible for the service to have some specific logic particular to working with classes of type `MyObj`.

In case 2, unless you use instanceof (avoid if possible), then you are risking a ugly `ClassCastException` which you would have to catch and handle.

Answer (score 3):

One reason why first scenario is better is that the `find(Class,String)` method now has knowledge of what its return value is being assigned to. Therefore, it is now capable of doing any relevant casts internally instead of simply hoping the correct type was returned. For example, suppose the `find` method locates a `String` object internally when called with `"someId"`. The `find` method may have a strategy for casting a `String` to a `MyObj` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't better. Arguably its worse except in very specific circumstances. Only time you need that kind of thing is where the target is going to need to call newInstance() (etc) on the class object - factory methods and stuff.

If you want to save electrons, BTW, this will also work

```
MyObj obj = someService.find((Class<MyObj>) null, "someId");
```